# LEDs and buttons - ready made

Tags: led, usb, controller

We want our first semester students to learn programming and see the results of their exercises on a LED matrix. Unfortunately, we can not start soldering with the guys in the first week, so we are looking for a led matrix with controller preassembled. Ideally the thing would also include one or more buttons and should be controlled/programmed with C. I could imagine that the product would be connected via USB. Also, the product should not be too expensive (max 15 euro/25 usd).

Do you have any idea how/where to get such a product (without me sitting there and soldering boards for 50 people)?

Comment: You want first-semester students to do USB programming?!

Comment: No, sorry. I would need the product to include a library which let's them turn on/off LEDs and ask for the button state.

Comment: This seems to be a 'shopping question', which is off-topic according to the [Help Centre](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help). I won't downvote, because I also teach, and this sort of situation is difficult to solve within a budget.

Comment: Can you commandeer the more skilled students to do the soldering? Then you only need to help fix their screw-ups.

Comment: I am relatively confident that there isn't a product under £20 because a local university paid students over the summer holiday to solder up something like that. I think they were paid for each working board, but it may have been an hourly rate (I know how I would pay :-) They did provide (very skilled) technician support to the students.

Comment: White plug-in proto board and a bunch of LED's and resistors?

Comment: The price would be very sensitive to the size of your LED matrix. What size are you aiming at? And alternative: write a library that simulates the LED matrix in a window, and have a few real sets of hardware to demonstrate the final product on.

Comment: Wouter: I had the same idea: to simulate it. But then I remembered my days with the iPhone simulator and it is just not the same. Also, currently I teach with console examples anyway. Regarding the size, I am flexible. I guess 8 led (in any arrangement) would be sufficient.

Comment: You mean 8, not 8x8? Then get an FT245 chip, it connects via USB and emulates a windows serial port, and outputs the byte you send to it on 8 pins. Attach LEDs (with series resistors) and you are done. Not as finished product, but it takes only a few components. Making a PCB for it would be most of the effort. For 50 pieces @ E15 I could probably do it. Contact me offline?

Comment: Thanks and thanks for the offer. I will check with my dean and come back to you if we decide to go that way.

Answer (score 3):

Get them to program using an Arduino, which is C/C++. The software is free, Open Source, and runs on popular platforms. It is programmed over USB, and can communicate with a host PC over USB.

Use Arduino Nano (clones), and push the pins into breadboard. (Nano clone is under £3, and breadboard under £2 from well-known shopping sites)

Use an LED matrix built around the MAX7219. (Under £2 from well-known shopping sites.)

Use a ready made set of buttons. A 4x4 button matrix is about £1.

Use ribbon cable, or ready made wires with female/male plugs and sockets to connect everything. (under £2 from well known shopping sites)

Total, approximately £10.

Also, get some LEDs, tactile switches and resistors to help them understand the fundamental ideas before using the LED matrix. (~ £1)

This assumes you have a PC of some type running Windows, Linux or OS X, to write programs, and run the Arduino tool chain.

Comment: Thanks that is probably what I am going to do. Thank you!